# How do you perform Asynchronous Query using BigQuery client library version 0.26.0-beta?

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems that my query execution is now performed synchronously rather than asynchronously using the latest (as of Oct. 17. 2017) version of the BigQuery libraries available via "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.26.0-beta".

I need to use the latest version so that I can use properly set the maxBillingTier option.

Here is my code-snippet:

```
QueryJobConfiguration request =
    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
        .setDefaultDataset(datasetId)
        .setMaximumBillingTier(MAX_BILLING_TIER)
        .build();

BigQuery.QueryOption pageSizeOption = BigQuery.QueryOption.of(
    BigQuery.QueryResultsOption.pageSize(PAGE_SIZE));
BigQuery.QueryOption maxWaitOption = BigQuery.QueryOption.of(
    BigQuery.QueryResultsOption.maxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_MILLIS));

QueryResponse response = null;
try {
      response = bigQuery.query(request,
                                pageSizeOption,
                                maxWaitOption);
} catch ( // exception-handling code deleted for brevity ) {
  ...
}
return response.getJobId();
```

A similarly formatted request using QueryRequest from version 0.24.0 instead of QueryJobConfiguration would have (quickly) returned the jobId, which I could then use to poll for status. Now, I suddenly have no simple way of reporting the status of the query to my calling code.

---

Update:
I was able to get asynchronous query results with this approach:

```
QueryJobConfiguration request =
    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
        .setDefaultDataset(datasetId)
        .setMaximumBillingTier(MAX_BILLING_TIER)
        .build();

JobInfo jobInfo = JobInfo
    .newBuilder(request)
    .setJobId(jobId)
    .build();

Job job = bigQuery.create(jobInfo);

QueryResponse response = job.getQueryResults(pageSizeOption,
                                             maxWaitOption);
return response.getJobId();
```

Of course, I need to add exception-handling, but that's the gist. However, it is far less elegant than the simpler format available in version 0.24.0-beta.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Would setting Priority to BATCH priority have an effect on this?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L578

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In fact, that is pretty much what I had, except I wanted Standard SQL rather than Legacy, as used in your example. What I found was that it runs synchronously rather than a-synch. Internally, that will eventually invoke this method to do the query:   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/349f3b0db216ba701ac3e0973e5cf7ce9439ba71/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Job.java#L275

Comment: Swapping legacy SQL for Standard is simple. I'm not convinced that you say this run sync. I'll test today.

Comment: It looks like the new synchronous mode was an intentional change checked in by vam-google. Checkin comments for checkin 2446 include the text:   "2) Make `BigQuery.query()` call synchronous (waits for query completion before return result), with jittered exponential backoff for polling (based on `gax.retrying` package)"